# Help with this quadratic system!

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have the system
$$\lambda x^2+\mu y^2=1$$
$$(x-g_1)^2+(y-g_2)^2=1$$
Where $\lambda,\mu>0,g_1,g_2\in\mathbb{R}$.

I am interested in characterizing when the above system, or the system obtained when the equalities are exchanged with $\leq$, have solution.

I tried to solve for $x$ and replace, but I got a polynomial in $y$ that I couldn't solve. Also I tried to use a nonlinear version of the Farkas Lemma that I found in internet, but I got nothing useful.

Every tool is allowed.

Thanks!

Comment: Try thinking more geometrically. Can you give your equations geometrical meaning? What happens for example if you choose $\lambda=\mu=1$ or $g_1=g_2=0$?

Comment: originally it was a geometrical problem. The elipse case $\lambda\not= \mu$ is much harder than when $\lambda=\mu$.

Comment: So you can reformulate your problem the following way: When does a circle with radius one and midpoint $(m_1,m_2)$ intersect an ellipse with parameters $\lambda,\mu$ centered at the origin?
To settle this question fix a midpoint $(m_1,m_2)$. And compute the closest point on the Ellipse to the midpoint depending on the parameters of the Ellipse. Then you will have the following situations: (a) your closest point(s) has distance bigger than one to the midpoint. In this case you have no intersection. (b) your closest point has distance $\leq 1$. In this case your equation has a solution.

Comment: P.s. In case (b) you need also to make sure that the farthest point on the ellipse lies outside the circle. Otherwise it could happen that the ellipse is entirely contained in the circle.

Comment: You won't be able to solve your system without solving a quartic function in general. If it was easily possible to solve your system, it would also be possible to find the intersection points of two arbitrary ellipses - you would only need to transform the given ellipses into a system like yours (which can easily be done), solve it and get the intersection points by reverting the transformation. As it is known to be difficult (it involves quartic functions) to find the intersection points of two ellipses, your system must obviously be difficult (involve quartic functions), too.

Comment: thanks @ReinhardMeier! All that I tried (including @asterisk 's idea) involves compute the root of a quartic polynomial, but I did not know that the problem of intersection of ellipes is difficult.

Comment: If you just want to detect overlaps algebraically, all you need is to determine the signs and multiplicities of some the roots. [This paper](http://i.cs.hku.hk/~ykchoi/quadrics/Ellipsoid_Separation.pdf) gives a number of conditions to check.